# Plotting standard deviation on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following code but Im having issues trying to make this plot the standard deviation for the vector 'Ibig'. When i run the code i get an error saying that 'x2' in the 8 isnt the same vector size. How can i fix this problem or is there another way to plot the standard deviation?

```
y = Ibig;
x = 1:numel(y);
std_dev = std(y);
curve1 = y + std_dev;
curve2 = y - std_dev;
x2 = [x, fliplr(x)];
inBetween = [curve1, fliplr(curve2)];
fill(x2, inBetween, 'g');
hold on;
plot(x, y, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image: What y looks like]

Comment: The question is unclear for me. What does _"Im having issues trying to find x2"_ mean? What is `x2`? What issues do you have?

Comment: Apologies, i have updated the description @ThomasSablik. Essentially i need to figure out a way to fill in the area between two line plots (In this case curve1 and curve2).

Comment: What format does `y` have? Your code works if `y` is a row vector (1 x n). It doesn't work for column vectors or arrays with higher dimension.

Comment: @jabaa have updated the description to show that its a (n x 1) column vector. Is there anyway that i can change this so that it is a row vector or is there another way to plot this as a standard deviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works with row vectors but not with column vectors. In your image you are showing a column vector. You have to transpose it:

```
y = Ibig.';
x = 1:numel(y);
std_dev = std(y);
curve1 = y + std_dev;
curve2 = y - std_dev;
x2 = [x, fliplr(x)];
inBetween = [curve1, fliplr(curve2)];
fill(x2, inBetween, 'g');
hold on;
plot(x, y, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```